# kendo-ui for Angular customizing LegendItemComponent

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Good morning, everyone. I need to customize my legend-item in donut chart. 
As I read in documentation I need to define the LegendItemVisualArgs object and initialize the createVisual() method.

Here I'm showing the way I've done it:

```
export class CustomLegendItemViewModel implements LegendItemVisualArgs {
options: any;
pointIndex: any;
sender: ChartComponent;
series: any;

createVisual(): Circle {
    const geometry = new GeomCircle([10, 10], 10);

    return new Circle(geometry);
}
```

After That I create this object in my Angular component:

```
export class ChartItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  visual: CustomLegendItemViewModel = new CustomLegendItemViewModel();
}
```

And in HTML code I try to bind my custom legend-item view to my object:

```
<kendo-chart>
            <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item [holeSize]="100"
                        type="donut" [data]="data2" [size]="20"
                        categoryField="kind" field="share">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="true">
                <kendo-chart-legend-item [visual]="visual"></kendo-chart-legend-item>
            </kendo-chart-legend>
        </kendo-chart>
```

And I've faced with error that

```
Uncaught TypeError: customVisual is not a function
at LegendItem.renderVisual (legend-item.js:112)
at LegendLayout.render (legend-layout.js:33)
at Legend.createItems (legend.js:101)
at new Legend (legend.js:27)
at Chart._getModel (chart.js:463)
at Chart._redraw (chart.js:279)
at Chart._noTransitionsRedraw (chart.js:1284)
at Chart._resize (chart.js:134)
at Chart.resize (chart.js:128)
at ChartComponent.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-charts/dist/es/chart.component.js.ChartComponent.resize (chart.component.js:389)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how can I solve it? Or just send some reference to customizing example.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/LegendItemComponent/) you need to provide a `function` to the `visual` input, but you are providing a object/class.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/LegendItemComponent/

Here is the documentation for Angular framework: the type of visual - is object. 

Looks like you find the kendo-ui for jQuery. I'm using Angular

Comment: When I open the link you provided I see that `visual` expects a `function`. (type: `(e: LegendItemVisualArgs) => Element`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API you need to provide a `function` to the `visual` input. ([API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/LegendItemComponent/))

In the code below I am binding the function `visualFn` to the input `visual`. ([Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/z2RhIkPNXkHGe6tonlxd?p=preview))

**html**

```
<kendo-chart>
    ...
    <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="true">
        <kendo-chart-legend-item [visual]="visualFn"></kendo-chart-legend-item>
    </kendo-chart-legend>
</kendo-chart>
```

**component**

```
public visualFn(e: SeriesVisualArgs): Group {
    const geometry = new GeomCircle([10, 10], 10);
    return new Circle(geometry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve this on angular like this. Based on jquery version -> http://dojo.telerik.com/iliGOJ/7

**component**

```
  public visualFn(e: SeriesVisualArgs): Layout {

    var color = e.options.markers.background;
    var labelColor = e.options.labels.color;
    var rect = new Rect([0, 0], [100, 50]);
    var layout = new Layout(rect, {
      spacing: 5,
      alignItems: "center"
    });

    var circleGeometry = new GeomCircle([0, 10], 4);
    var circle = new Circle(circleGeometry, {
      stroke: { color: "none" },
      fill: {color: color}
    });
    var marker = circle;

    var label = new Text(e.series.name, [0, 0], {
      fill: { color: labelColor }
    });

    layout.append(marker, label);
    layout.reflow();

    return layout;
  }
```

**html**

```
<kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" [offsetX]="200">
    <kendo-chart-legend-item [visual]="visualFn"></kendo-chart-legend-item>
</kendo-chart-legend>
```